# Thingspeak: message limit, update limit and bulk updates

Tags: sensors, data-transfer

I am looking at [ThingSpeak](https://www.thingspeak.com) for logging sensor data.

I would like to log three different variables at a frequency up one datapoint per second. This would be 86400 samples per day or 259200 values per day.

The thingspeak "pricing" page says that on free accounts:

1. "The number of messages" is limites to ~ 8200 per day.
2. "The message update interval" is limited to >15 seconds.

**My question is: for ThingSpeak, what counts as a "message"? Is it each http request or each sample?**

I.e. can I collect my samples for, say 120 seconds, and post them as a bulk update? This would be only 720 http requests per day but still 86400 samples per day. Would this fit into the ThingSpeak limits?

Answer (score 3):

Accorinding to this post, [API Rate Limit by](https://community.thingspeak.com/forum/thingspeak-api/api-rate-limit-by/) on the ThingSpeak API Forum, one message means **one HTTP request** and there is no limit about how many fields do you want to update with that request or about the size of the payload.

Brief of the question:

> I have a channel for temperatures with 4 fields mapped to 4 thermal
>   probes [...]
>
> - Do I need to wait 15 seconds between POSTs to each field?
> - Do I need group all 4 sensor readings into a single POST request?
> - Are my assumptions correct or should separate sensors really be on
>     separate channels etc…

---

The answer:

> You can send all your data for the 4 fields as one POST, or you can
>   make a separate channel for each of your sensors.